# MySQL: Query with AS variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

I made a query using which I create a variable accountId, I can not reuse accountId in my subquery why?

Here my code:

```
SELECT userId AS accountId,
        (SELECT recommended FROM ads_connections WHERE byUserId = accountId AND throughUserId = accountId AND adId = :recommendedAdId) AS recommended,
        --
        (SELECT requestStatus FROM ads_recommends_requests WHERE 
                                                                userId = :currentUserId AND 
                                                                requestFromUserId = accountId AND 
                                                                advertisementId = :statusAdId) AS requestStatus,

        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ads_recommends_requests 
                WHERE 
                    requestFromUserId = accountId AND 
                    advertisementId = :countAdId AND 
                    requestStatus = '1'
        ) AS recommendedTimes
        --
        FROM user_contacts

        WHERE userId IN " . $myCircleString . "
        AND phoneNumber = :phoneNumber
        AND (SELECT fictive FROM users WHERE id = userId) = 0
        ";
```

Output example:

```
"data": [
    {
        "userId": 0,
        "accountId": 2,
        "fictive": false,
        "name": "Mickael",
        "phoneNumber": "0584688888",
        "review": "0",
        "liked": false,
        "recommended": 0,
        "requestStatus": 0,
        "recommendedTimes": 0
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Alias cannot be used instead of accounID use userID

Comment: So how can I do it?

Comment: I'm guessing all these sub queries could be replaced with joins would you like to add sample data and expected output as text to the question?

Comment: Please look my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER RESPONSE**

Create variable in this way:

```
SELECT @acctId := userId AS accountId
```

And use it:

```
(SELECT requestStatus FROM ads_recommends_requests WHERE
                   userId = :currentUserId AND
                   requestFromUserId = @acctId AND
                   advertisementId = :statusAdId) AS requestStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this-

```
SELECT userId AS accountId,
        (SELECT recommended FROM ads_connections WHERE byUserId = userId AND throughUserId = userId AND adId = :recommendedAdId) AS recommended,
        --
        (SELECT requestStatus FROM ads_recommends_requests WHERE 
                                                                userId = :currentUserId AND 
                                                                requestFromUserId = userId AND 
                                                                advertisementId = :statusAdId) AS requestStatus,

        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ads_recommends_requests 
                WHERE 
                    requestFromUserId = userId AND 
                    advertisementId = :countAdId AND 
                    requestStatus = '1'
        ) AS recommendedTimes
        --
        FROM user_contacts

        WHERE userId IN " . $myCircleString . "
        AND phoneNumber = :phoneNumber
        AND (SELECT fictive FROM users WHERE id = userId) = 0
        ";
```

Comment: It does not work, maybe because there is a conflict because lrequestFromUserId = userId the top line is userId =: currentUserId, so the server is confused?

Comment: No server will not get confused because :currentUserId is your inout and userID is from table column